# How to show multiple fields from data in tooltip in a multi series highchart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I have two jsondata objects and I want to display multiple charts in the same highchart. One of the data objects have multiple fields as shown below.I want to use points c, d , e in the tooltip but I am not able to display it.

> ohlc.push([a:Date.UTC(2017,11,8), b: 0.67, c: 1, d: 2, e:0]);

> volume.push([Date.UTC(2017,11,8), 3]);

This is what I have written so far. But this.point.b and other points appear as undefined.

```
series: [{
    type: 'line',
    name: 'Sentiment',
    data: ohlc
}, {
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Comments',
    data: volume,
}]
// Add formatter
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %B %d, %Y',this.x) + '<br />';
        $.each(this.points, function () {
             if( this.series.name == 'Sentiment')
                s += '<b> '+this.series.name + ': </b>' +
                     this.point.b +' :::: '+this.point.c+' :::::'+this.point.d;
             });
             return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
    // End formatter
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jklwerq/m75skLhb/23/

Comment: `this` has all the data you need. Console it in your formatter and get whatever data you want to use from it

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, thanks for responding. I have added a demo link. All I see when I console this is [object][object].

Comment: @Rache would you like to achieve something like is done in this demo? http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1zxouedj/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, Thanks. 2 questions. why is the values not correct. The positive, negative and neutral values are all numbers but the values of positive and negative displayed are wrong. Also the month is off. Do I have to give month -1?

Comment: How can I move the comment x axis to Volume

Comment: @Rache, sorry I didn't check your data. Be aware that the month calculation starts from 0. The negative displayed is a boolean because a point could have this property. I am afraid that you will need to change the name of this property in your data.

Comment: `How can I move the comment x axis to Volume` here I dont understand?

Comment: Thanks for explaining Sebastian. I just realized I am actually using stockchart. Can you look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jklwerq/m75skLhb/62/ . This is the example I followed in my project. Once I added my own labels to the fields it doesn't work.

Comment: Or in your example itself: http://jsfiddle.net/jklwerq/58fLnu3j/6/ ; how can I bring the bar chart that denotes 'Volume' position from x (date) axis instead be plotted in the Sentiment section.

Comment: @Rache you need to assign your column series to the second yAxis which you have defined. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tspghu4e/

Comment: @Rache if you want help with your stockchart demo - please simplified it. Currently is too messy to work on it.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianWędzel I had removed yAxis: 1, during my revisions. Thanks a lot for your support.